# syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Tags: php, html, laravel, search

I am building a search filter, which was working fine until I added another 2 options to search by and now I get that error and for the life of me I can't figure out what I am missing.

it is literally just the last two that I added, but I don't know if it is just because I am looking at it too long that I can't see it.

```
 public function index(Request $request){

    $title = $request->get('title');

    $type = $request->get('type');

    $category = $request->get('category_id');
    
    $province = $request->get('province');

    $brand= $request->get('brand_id');

    $address = $request->get('address');

    $race = $request->get('race');

    $dealer_experience = $request->get('dealer_experience');

    if($title||$type||$category||$address||$brand||$race ||$dealer_experience) {
        $candidates = Profile::query();
        if ($title) {
            $candidates = $candidates->where('title','LIKE','%'.$title.'%');
        }
      
        
        if ($category) {
            $candidates = $candidates->where('category_id',$category);
        }

          
        if ($brand) {
            $candidates = $candidates->where('brand_id',$brand);
        }

        if ($type) {
            $candidates = $candidates->where('type',$type);
            
        }

         
        
        if ($address) {
            $candidates = $candidates->where('address','LIKE','%'.$address.'%');
        }

        if ($race ) {
            $race  = $race ->where('race',$race);
        }

        if ($dealer_experience) {
            $dealer_experience = $dealer_experience->where('dealer_experience',$dealer_experience);
            
        }    
    }   

        $candidates = $candidates->where('profile_status',1)->paginate(5);
        return view('profile.allcandidates',compact('candidates')); 
    }
    else
    {
        $candidates= Profile::latest()->where('profile_status',1)->paginate(2);
        return view('profile.allcandidates',compact('candidates'));

    }

}

any and all help would be appreciated..
```

Comment: Voting to close because this is a typo. The issue is mismatched curly braces.

Comment: You should format your code before posting. In this case if properly indented the code the problem would have probably been obvious to you as well so you wouldn't even have needed to post anything

Comment: @apokryfos I fixed the curly brace, getting " syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)" error now

Comment: You mean you removed the curly brace before `$candidates` ?

Comment: @apkryfos I managed to come right, but I have a new issue where I use the search function I get "Call to a member function where() on string" ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a mess. Your inconsistent indentation is not helping you.

```php
public function index(Request $request){

    $title = $request->get('title');

    $type = $request->get('type');

    $category = $request->get('category_id');
    
    $province = $request->get('province');

    $brand= $request->get('brand_id');

    $address = $request->get('address');

    $race = $request->get('race');

    $dealer_experience = $request->get('dealer_experience');

    if($title||$type||$category||$address||$brand||$race ||$dealer_experience) {
        $candidates = Profile::query();
        if ($title) {
            $candidates = $candidates->where('title','LIKE','%'.$title.'%');
        }
      
        
        if ($category) {
            $candidates = $candidates->where('category_id',$category);
        }

          
        if ($brand) {
            $candidates = $candidates->where('brand_id',$brand);
        }

        if ($type) {
            $candidates = $candidates->where('type',$type);
            
        }

         
        
        if ($address) {
            $candidates = $candidates->where('address','LIKE','%'.$address.'%');
        }

        if ($race ) {
            $race  = $race ->where('race',$race);
        }

        if ($dealer_experience) {
            $dealer_experience = $dealer_experience->where('dealer_experience',$dealer_experience);
            
        }    
    }   

        $candidates = $candidates->where('profile_status',1)->paginate(5);
        return view('profile.allcandidates',compact('candidates')); 
    }
    else
    {
        $candidates= Profile::latest()->where('profile_status',1)->paginate(2);
        return view('profile.allcandidates',compact('candidates'));

    }

}
```

Leverage the functionality of your IDE to clean up your indentation automatically. Once you do so, it's pretty easy to spot the additional closing bracket.

Comment: thank you for helping, I will do my best to do this, getting " syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)" error now